# Problem while setting a specific rotation to a humanoid robot in webots

Tags: webots

I have a humanoid robot which is something like a modified version of robotis op3. When I change its rotation, the robot surprisingly happens to face ridiculous problems. For example, its joints start to take apart or merge into each other. Does anyone has any idea about this?

Comment: I checked the Robotis OP3 and it seems it doesn't have this problem. Can you confirm? What kind of modification did you do with respect to the OP3?

Comment: Are you changing the rotation often? For example to perform numerical optimization in a loop?

Comment: @OlivierMichel Thank you, the problem was because I did not make the vector unit length. I thought the simulator would do it automatically.

Comment: @DavidMansolino No, actually I want to do some experiments on my humanoid robot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments of the issue, this was due to non-normalized rotation values not handled correctly be Webots.

This was fixed in Webots in https://github.com/cyberbotics/webots/pull/1459.